# Linux: Find the second biggest file/directory in size using commands

Tags: linux, disk-usage, sort, size

**Introduction**

Find the second biggest file/directory in size using commands.

**What I have**

```
du /etc/ -hsx * | sort -rh | head -2
```

This command shows me two lines which, by the options I've chosen, gets me the 2 biggest files/directories inside /etc/.

**Question**

What if I only want to find the second biggest file? How can I do it?

Example, by doing the command `sudo du /etc/ -hsx * | sort -rh | head -2 | tail -1`

I get the result

> 1.5M snap

but what I expected is to get only it's name, not the size or else. Just the name. I've also read that can be done with the `ls` command too.

Comment: Do you want  *size* (as reported by `ls -l` for instance), or *disk usage* (as reported by `ls -s` or `du` for instance). For directories, do you want to consider the size/disk usage of the directories, or of all the files and directories accessible through them recursively? Note that files can be referenced in more than one directory, but if you do `du dir1 dir2` the size of those files referenced in both will only be accounted to `dir1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that by *size*, you mean the disk usage of non-directory files or the cumulative disk usage of all the files referenced through the directory files (as your usage of `du` suggests), with GNU utilities, you could do:

```
sudo LC_ALL=C du -al0d1 /etc |
  sort -zrn |
  tail -zn+2 |
  head -zn1 |
  cut -zf2- |
  tr '\0' '\n'
```

The `tail`+`head`+`cut` can also be replaced with `sed -z $'1d;s/^[^\t]*\t//;q'`.

Notes:

- with `du /etc/ -hsx *` (which assumes GNU `find` and that `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is not in the environment as you're using options *after* non-option arguments), you're getting the disk usage of `/etc` and of all the non-hidden files in the *current* directory.
- using `-a` and `-d1` (a GNU extension) solves all the problems of `*` excluding hidden directories or reaching the limit of number of arguments.
- `-h` is not only non-portable, but you also lose a lot of precision (so will likely make you report the wrong file), and you make `sort` job more difficult, so it's quite counter-productive.
- without `-l` (a GNU extension), hard links are counted only once so if `some-large-file` is found both as `/etc/dir1/some-large-file` and `/etc/dir2/other-link-to-some-large-file`, the disk space occupied by `some-large-file` is only accounted to one of those directories by `du`.
- newline is as valid a character as any in a file name (macOS actually used to come with file names with newline characters in `/etc` IIRC). So generally you can't use line-based text processing to deal with those. Most GNU utilities have `-z` or `-0` options to work with NUL delimited records.
- Note that in that sorted list, the first record will be for `/etc`. So by taking the second record, we're actually reporting the heaviest file/dir in `/etc`, not second-heaviest.
- If there are ties, the file name that sorts last in the locale collation order will be chosen via the last-resort comparison done by `sort` without `-s`.

Answer (score 2):

> What if I only want to find the second biggest file? How can I do it?

Obligatory zsh option:

```
zsh -c 'print -r /etc/**/*(DoL[-2])'
```

This invokes zsh and asks it to print the argument, which is:

- a recursive filename expansion `**/*`
- sorted (`o`rdered) by size (`L`ength), in increasing size
- `D` enables `dotglob` for that one glob, so also considers hidden files or files in hidden directories.
- limited to the 2nd-to-last entry in the list (`[-2]`)

Answer (score 0):

With **sed**, just add:

```
 | sed -n 2p
```

And no need to do that extra **head**.

Complete command:

```
du /etc/ -hsx * | sort -rh | sed -n 2p
```

If you want to stick to using **head** after sort, then add this **tail**:

```
 | tail +2
```

Complete command:

```
du /etc/ -hsx * | sort -rh | head -2 | tail +2
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably one of the options would be to flip the result using `sort` again and use `head -1`? Like:

```
du /etc/ -hsx * | sort -rh | head -2 | sort -r | head -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use tail

```
du /etc/ -hsx * | sort -rh | head -2 | tail -1
```